# Defining a top level go template

Tags: go, template-engine

Suppose that I have tow text files (go templates):

**child.tmpl**

```
TEXT1 
Hello {{ . }}
```

**top.tmpl**

```
TEXT2
{{ template "child.tmpl" "argument"}}
```

the `child.tmpl` template is nested in `top.tmpl`

A typical program to parse them will be :

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("child.tmpl", "top.tmpl")
    t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "top.tmpl", nil)
}
```

Is there any method the pass the template to be embedded in the top-level template as an argument using the `{{ . }}` notation ?
something like `{{ template {{.}} "argument" }}`

- More generally, what is the best way to define a layout template so I can use it like a top-level template to multiple child templates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two accepted ways to solve your problem:

The first involves writing your own template-inclusion function and registering it as an [`template.FuncMap`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#FuncMap) with your template through [`template.Funcs`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs).

The other way is to use `{{define xxx}}` blocks in your *child* templates. Then you could have two different files that define the same template:

- file1.html: `{{define body}}...{{end}}`
- file2.html: `{{define body}}...{{end}}`

Parse the correct file depending on your needs and in your *parent* template just do `{{template body "argument"}}`.

In my opinion, the first option is more flexible.

Comment: Rats. I was hoping the same thing. The following kludge didn't work:

    {{ with $x := .BodyPage }}{{ template $x .Content }}{{end}}

Since I'm precompiling the templates at program start, I ended up making a `map[string]*template.Template` which isn't ideal, either. I'll investigate the custom function method, although as I think about it, it will **either** end up loading the files off disk at runtime and parsing, or I'll end up with a map of precompiled templates.